# Referring to objects(tables) in other schema or user in Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Am accessing table data from other schema and inserting into current schema table in oracle procedure, but am  unable to compile the procedure getting error "Error(5,27): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

But where as when I select data from table(in other schema) directly am able to fetch the data but not in procedure. I have all required permissions as well.

Below is the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_SCHEMA
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT * FROM Other_User_Schema.Table2

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you acquired privileges to `select` data from `other_user_schema.table2` via **role**. If that's so, **grant that privilege directly to your user** because that won't work in named PL/SQL procedures.